# If there's a constexpr if statement, why not other constexpr statements too?

Tags: c++, c++17

Is there any reason only `if constexpr` to be included in C++17?

I could do this:

```
template <int N>
constexpr int fib() {
    if constexpr (N == 1 || N == 2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return fib<N - 1>() + fib<N - 2>();
    }
}
```

Why haven't the C++ committee considered `switch constexpr` too?

```
template <int N>
constexpr int fib() {
    switch constexpr (N) {
        case 1:
        case 2: return 1;
        default: return fib<N - 1>() + fib<N - 2>();
    }
}
```

It looked much cooler with `switch constexpr`

Or even a premature compile-time loop unwind with `for constexpr`/`while constexpr` without the use of template substitution/recursive template function:

```
constexpr void printFoo() {
    for constexpr (auto i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << fib<i>() << endl;
    }
}
```

Will they be included in C++20/future versions of C++?

Comment: Write a proposal then.

Comment: "It looked much cooler" is not a good enough reason. I believe we only got `if constexpr` because it would've taken longer if we tried to include the whole lot at the same time; `if constexpr`'s benefits and drawbacks are easier to weigh than `for constexpr` or `switch constexpr`, for example.

Comment: @HenriMenke I don't think I'm prestigious enough to do so

Comment: _"It looked much **cooler** with switch constexpr"_ . Get ready to be trolled

Comment: If you are willing to give your precious time to research and write a good proposal, you are prestigious enough.

Comment: `switch (x) { default: for (i = 0; i != 4;) if (i > 7) case 1: i += 3; else case 2: i -= 1; }` is a valid statement. Now what about `switch constexpr (x) { default: for (i = 0; i != 4;) if (i > 7) case 1: i += 3; else case 2: i -= 1; }`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "Why isn't X a language feature?" is not really an answerable question to anybody's satisfaction.

Answer (score 28):

`if constexpr` was proposed relatively close to C++17 being finalized.

Embellishments (like `switch`) might have deferred its inclusion.

Fancy ones like forced loop unrolling would certainly have.

It takes real work to change the C++ standard.  You have to implement it yourself in a compiler as proof it can be done, convince other compiler writers it should be easy or worth the effort, work out how it should be worded in the standard to be clear and unambiguous, convince the other members of the committee that your change isn't just cruft on the language, etc.

It does not require a reason for something **not** to happen.  Things don't happen all the time.  C++ improving isn't some natural process that occurs unless someone stops it,

Tl;dr: because you didn't propose it and husband it through standardization.  Get started today and it might be in C++20.  "I am not worthy" of proposing is not an excuse: this is *work* that needs doing, not some granted boon for being awesome.  One becomes awesome by doing the work.  "I am lazy" is an excuse, one I am intimately familiar with.

Comment: It's not a formal requirement that you have to implement it in a compiler. There aren't that much formal requirements, and those are mostly procedural. But it certainly helps to convince WG21. In this case, it's syntactic sugar. The chief WG21 concern then isn't whether it can be implemented, but whether the semantics are well-defined and not conflicting with other parts of the language.

Comment: @msalters Is constexor general loop unrolling really just sugar?  I mean, specifying what is ok and what is not.  Does the address of the index variable change, or not?  Either seems madness.,

Comment: What _is_ the address of an index variable anyway, inside a `constexpr` loop? It seems logical to just forbid taking the address outright. That's perfectly explainable/teachable: "the compiler executes the loop at compile time, so there's no runtime address".

Comment: @msalters So I cannot pass a reference to that value?  Ie, no ODR usage.  Or should a temporary be instantiated?  What if the loop is `for(int x=0; test(x); inc(x))`?

Answer (score 13):

The C++ standards committee does not, in general, add new features just because they "look cool". Each new feature is only added after a paper is submitted that proposes meticulously crafted legalese that precisely specifies the feature's syntax and semantics, which often goes through multiple revisions as all the implications are hashed out by experts.

This provides a natural barrier to adding new features: if the functionality it would add to the language is not enough to make that gruelling experience worthwhile, then nobody will bother proposing it formally.

`if constexpr` is a valuable addition to the language (try rewriting the code not to use it and you'll see why) and it was not that complicated to specify: if the condition is true then the second substatement is discarded, otherwise the first substatement is discarded.

In contrast, `switch constexpr` would pose much greater difficulties in wording because of the greater complexities of `switch` statements. (You are welcome to try, though.) For example, you have a natural expectation of how this should work:

```
switch constexpr (x) {
  case 1:
    bar<x>();
    if constexpr(y) { break; }
  case 2:
    baz<x>();
}
```

namely that if `x` is 1 and `y` is true then `baz<x>` is not instantiated, but if `x` is 1 and `y` is false then `baz<x>` *is* instantiated. If you want these semantics, you need to figure out the standardese, which will have to specify an effective procedure for determining exactly which statements to discard (keep in mind that these `if`s and `switch`es can be arbitrarily nested). If you don't want these semantics, your `switch constexpr` is probably no more powerful than a bunch of `if constexpr`'s anyway but will have restrictions compared to the normal `switch` statement.

These difficulties increase further with `for constexpr`. Now, it might be worth it. But someone has to put in the effort.

Comment: An initial paper could probably establish a transform from `switch constexpr` to an equivalent but more verbose set of `if constexpr` statements. First test the WG21 waters to see if there's sufficient interest. If there's good feedback, a second paper can then propose the actual standardese.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment.  You can have compile-time loop unrolling in the Intel(R) Compiler using `#pragma unroll`.

```
void bar();

constexpr void foo() {
    #pragma unroll(10)
    for (auto i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        bar();
    }
}

void baz()
{
    foo();
}
```

<kbd>[Live example](https://godbolt.org/g/9phc8j)</kbd>  on Godbolt to prove unrolling.

Comment: It isn't the unrolling that is interesting, but the index variable being a compile time constant within the loop.